# tf quaternion explained

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, im a bit confused about the quaternion convention. If i define a tf::Quaternion (0,1,0,0), what is the direction of the vector? A diagram would be appreciated. Im used to euler convention

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221597/tf-quaternion-explained/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this page will be helpful for you:
http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToEuler/index.htm

(At the end of the page there is a tool for angles conversion)
In the same page, you can also find other kind of angle conversions.

---

Originally posted by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) with karma: 123 on 2015-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0